Setting up L2TP on DigitalOcean Droplet is not working
I have set up L2TP VPN server on a DigitalOcean Droplet. I am using Mikrotik RB as client. I have completed the set up and the status on the l2tp interface on mikrotik shows "connected" status. I want to be able to login to the mikrotik via VPN_SERVER_IP:port  and the mikrotik login credentials. I have set static IP for the VPN clients as well as port forwarding, but I still can't login.
Mikrotik interface status:


You need to provide additional detail on how this is relevant to Ubuntu otherwise your question will get deleted.  And what version of Ubuntu are you using?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Sorry, your question is unclear. Where are you using Ubuntu?
